# How to convert the Voltage source into a Current source

Tags: voltage, current, conversion, source

[image]

I'm confused about how to convert the voltage source into a current source so that I can derive a NAM equation.
I've looked around for help but most of it tended to be of simple examples where the voltage source was directly in series with a resistor.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: You cannot convert between a voltage and a current source by themselves, only between a voltage source in series with an impedance and a current source in parallel with one, ie Thévenin and Norton models.

Comment: Do you know how to use the loop current analysis of a circuit? Using that, you don't need to convert the voltage source, you take it into account in the equations.

Comment: What's the NAM equation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can convert the L/C/R2 network from a star to a triangle.

You can then further simplify the network.  You get an impedance in parallel with R1, one in parallel with the current source and one in parallel with the voltage source.

The latter impedance can be "ignored" (except if you need to determine the current provided by V, but you can add it later).

You then have an impedance in series with the voltage source.  Etc.

I hope this helps.

Comment: With the two reactive components, you will need to know the frequency of the sources. If it's being assumed as DC, that simplifies to open-circuit capacitor and short-circuit inductor.